# In GA360 data in BigQuery I have duplicate visitNumber for fullVisitorId. What factors could cause this?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

What more can I say. A small but significant number of visitors have multiple matching visit numbers that are definitely distinct visits. I confirm with the following,

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, visitNumber, visitStartTime
FROM `<my_project>.<id>.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE fullVisitorId = 'a_visitor_I_know_has_duplicates'
ORDER BY visitStartTime
```

Which outputs

| fullVistitorId | visitNumber | vistitStartTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a_visitor_I_know_has_duplicates | 1 | 1518963968 |
| a_visitor_I_know_has_duplicates | 2 | 1518998917 |
| a_visitor_I_know_has_duplicates | 1 | 1542095106 |
| a_visitor_I_know_has_duplicates | 2 | 1542119587 |

I would imagine that rows 3 and 4 should actually be 3 and 4. Why is this? My suspicion is that these individuals either upgrade their browser, clear cache, or something akin to these. The documentation states

| Field Name | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fullVisitorId | STRING | The unique visitor ID. |
| visitNumber | INTEGER | The session number for this user. If this is the first session, then this is set to 1. |
| visitNumber | INTEGER | The session number for this user. If this is the first session, then this is set to 1. |

I've found is not helpful. If there is better documentation please share. Could anyone give me reasons why my visitor's visit numbers are duplicating?

Comment: No debugging details = question closed for missing debugging details. Make sure to include input tables, current output and expected output in your post as well. Help us help you.

Comment: These tables are public info they are described in the link I posted. The expected output is implied by the question. Its a simple question that will take someone with real knowledge of the system to solve.

Comment: Relying on links as main source for solving the problem is an additional flaw, because if links get corrupted or removed, future readers of this post won't be able to make any good use out of it. You can have your own idea and it's fine, this is just how SO works.